# GTK+3 file chooser in a non-GTK application

Tags: c, gtk3, filechooser

I have a C project (on Linux) which does not use GTK at all, but I would like to use GTK only for some specific tasks like selecting a file (file chooser dialog). So I have no GTK parent window, no gtk main loop, etc, I only want a file chooser dialog, which should block the execution of my program till user selected a file (or cancelled) and I don't use GTK then after that ever. What I've tried:

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html

I used the code at "Typical usage", first example. I put gtk_init(&argc, &argv) at the start of my program, and when I need the file chooser, I call a function with code from that example (I use parent as NULL, since there is no parent). The result is a flashing window for a fraction of second, then SIGSEGV. Before that I have this message:

```
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

I already read questions/answers on this message here at stackoverflow, but crashing the application is a more serious thing for me. I've also tried to put this:

```
gtk_widget_show_all(dialog);
```

after gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new() which causes no crash, I can select the file, but then I have the SIGSEGV again around gtk_file_chooser_get_filename().

When using gdb, I got this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x3c3) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:67
```

Can you help me what mistake I did? I am not familiar with GTK programming too much, so I tried to use examples from the manual, but it does not seem to work. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You cannot use widgets without a gtk mainloop.</strike>

Well, it seems I was wrong. My sincere apologies! I *had* actually tried to do this before and the conclusions were exactly what I described. But the issue has bugged me for the last days, so I did some more digging and experimenting and came up with the following program:

```
/* -*- Mode: C; indent-tabs-mode: t; c-basic-offset: 4; tab-width: 8 -*-  */
/*
 * main.c
 * Copyright (C) 2015 John Coppens <john@jcoppens.com>
 * 
 * standalone_filechooser is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it
 * under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
 * Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 * 
 * standalone_filechooser is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
 * WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 * See the GNU General Public License for more details.
 * 
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along
 * with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget *
create_filechooser_dialog(char *init_path, GtkFileChooserAction action)
{
  GtkWidget *wdg = NULL;

  switch (action) {
    case GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SAVE:
      wdg = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Save file", NULL, action,
        "Cancel", GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
        "Save", GTK_RESPONSE_OK,
        NULL);
      break;

    case GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN:
      wdg = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Open file", NULL, action,
        "Cancel", GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
        "Open", GTK_RESPONSE_OK,
        NULL);
      break;

    case GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SELECT_FOLDER:
    case GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_CREATE_FOLDER:
      break;
  }

  return wdg;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *wdg;
  char *fname = "";

  if (argc == 2)
    fname = argv[1];

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  wdg = create_filechooser_dialog(fname, GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN);
  if (gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(wdg)) == GTK_RESPONSE_OK) {
    printf("%s", gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(wdg)));
    return(0);
  } else  
    return (1);
}
```

You can call the dialog from another program (or even the terminal) with

```
standalone_filechooser [default file]
```

If `default file` is provided (no brackets), it'll be selected. If a file is selected, it will be printed on `stdout`, else the program will return with error=1

There is still a small issue with running a widget without main window, which causes a message to be sent to `stderr`: `GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged`. I think this is really a bug (and [it might be solved](https://github.com/voldyman/MarkMyWords/issues/22) in a more recent version of gtk3). As the message is sent to `stderr`, it shouldn't interfere with normal use.

Comment: Or, as a alternative to using GTK at all, you may want to consider running [`zenity`](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/file-selection.html.en) as a subprocess.

Comment: I thought that too (with gtk main loop) but that gtk_dialog_run() felt do the trick. Also please note that with just the example I've mentioned, the window is shown, just for only a fraction of second. However I have the feeling that it's some kind of linking issue, as I use SDL too, and sdl2-config --cflags / --libs uses -D_REENTRANT while gtk seems to want -pthread switch for gcc, since gdb reports crash in the nptl/thread stuff, I just think about some conflict here? But OK, I'll try your idea, it looks more polished solution anyway, I'll see, and tell+accept if it was oK! THANKS!

Comment: @duskwuff Nice idea, partly: I'll check source of zenity :-) Maybe it helps to create a simple filechooser, the right way (TM). :) I wouldn't like to use external programs too much if it's possible anyway ...

Comment: This doesn't work if you need to run code after the dialog is closed. since the main loop isn't running, it never closes the dialog and it just freezes.
the example only works because the program ends immediately.